# HTMLElement type for <strong>, <cite>, <article>, and others

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom, webapi

What are the [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) types for elements such as

- `<strong>`
- `<cite>`
- `<article>`
- and many others

?

According to MDN's [HTML elements reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element), there are many more elements than there are types under `HTMLElement` (see [this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API)).

I'm doing some processing on elements with TypeScript, and would like to store references to them with the most specific type possible. While many other elements have clearly-named  types (such as [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement), [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), and [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement)), the elements I've listed above do not seem to have any corresponding type.

Comment: MDN lists the "DOM Interface" as "HTMLElement" for [`<strong>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) and [`<article>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article). However, [`<cite>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite) says "HTMLElement Up to Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 4) inclusive, Firefox implements the HTMLSpanElement interface for this element."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its probably just HTMLElement

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('div').constructor);
console.log(document.getElementById('table').constructor);
console.log(document.getElementById('img').constructor);
console.log(document.getElementById('strong').constructor);
console.log(document.getElementById('cite').constructor);
console.log(document.getElementById('article').constructor);
```

```html
<strong id="strong">strong</strong>
<div id="div">div</div>
<cite id="cite">cite</cite>
<article id="article">article</article>
<table id="table"><tr><td><img id="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/460d2e9d0a84c78e6a5c141a51eb3ab9?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"></td</tr></table>
```

Comment: Not only does this answer the question, but provides a method for determining the type for any arbitrary element.